# Obtain ssh version externally using nmap

Tags: nmap

I would like to know if I can obtain ssh version using `nmap` of my external vps.

```
nmap -p 22 sV <domainname>
```

result:

22/tcp filtered ssh

Is there another `nmap` syntax so I can obtain ssh service version?
Just want to obtain the ssh service version of my external vps.
I tried alot of `nmap` commands but probably there's a struggle in-between like a firewall, which causes a filtered state. My own network is behind a DrayTek Device. Maybe a possible cause?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nmap option `--badsum` is able to provide insight about the existence of a firewall. A non firewall device that runs a full network stack will silently drop a bad checksum. In the case that your scan reaches an end device, you would expect to see the same result as your `-sV` scan. A firewall may offer a different reply to the `--badsum`.

The answer to your question regarding version, is that `-sV` is ideal, however `-A` may run some scripts that return useful information. You can also run `--script=sshv1` or another specific script that is ssh related. More script options are here [nmap scripts.](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is probably the info I need. I will look at this when I’m home.